# Problema con expresión regular en palabras con caracteres especiales o tildes

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo una expresión regular donde extraigo palabra por palabra y enumero las palabras con su respectivo orden

```
let text = `En este campo las respuestas deben ir entre corchetes ejemplo El [oso polar] es de la Antartida y el [oso pardo] es de selva.`;
let cont=0 

text.match(/\[([\w\s]*)\]|[\w]*/g)
  .forEach((item) => {
    if (item !== '') {
    cont++
      console.log(item+" "+cont);
    }
  });
```

Estas palabras se dividen y me dan un orden, el problema parte cuando las palabras **contienen tildes** como "Antártida" o palabras que tienen coma adelante o dos puntos como "corchetes," y "ejemplo:"

```
let text = `En este campo las respuestas deben ir entre corchetes, ejemplo: El [oso polar] es de la Antártida y el [oso pardo] es de selva.`;
let cont=0 

text.match(/\[([\w\s]*)\]|[\w]*/g)
  .forEach((item) => {
    if (item !== '') {
    cont++
      console.log(item+" "+cont);
    }
  });
```

¿Alguna idea de como ajustar la expresión regular para que tome las palabras con coma adelante y dos puntos adelantes o tilde como una sola palabra?

Comment: Hola, una duda en el caso de las comas o puntos, ¿quieres que salga por ejemplo **corchetes,** o **corchetes** y luego la coma?

Comment: *"Problemas con expresion regular"*... ¿Qué tal si conviertes el **título de la pregunta** en una **pregunta**? Así parece una pregunta, y no una búsqueda de google, o un tícket al departamento de desarrollo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu usas la clase de caracter **`\w`**, que sirve para buscar coincidencias con caracteres alfanuméricos, pero **no coincide** con caracteres `Unicode` (que son las palabras o vocales acentuadas), que es justamente el problema que tienes.

Entonces necesitamos encontrar una clase de caracter que coincida **con cualquier caracter** (incluyendo las letras acentuadas).

---

Según [**la documentación**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) (traducido al español):

> **Unicode Categories**:
>
> *Además de las complicaciones, Unicode también trae nuevas posibilidades. Una es que cada carácter Unicode pertenece a una determinada categoría. Puede hacer coincidir un solo carácter que pertenezca a la categoría "letra" con **\p{L}**. Puede hacer coincidir un solo carácter que no pertenezca a esa categoría con **\P{L}.***
>
> - ***\p{L}** o **\p{Letter}**: Cualquier tipo de letra de cualquier idioma.*

Es decir, con la clase de caracter **`\p{L}`** nos permite encontrar cualquier caracter incluyendo a los caracteres `Unicode`.

---

Entonces, en tu expresión regular:

```
text.match(/\[([\w\s]*)\]|[\w]*/g)
```

Solamente tenemos que cambiar los `\w` por `\p{L}`:

```
text.match(/\[([\p{L}\s]*)\]|[\p{L}]*/g)
```

Y usamos la bandera `/gu`, ya que `u` habilita el soporte para caracteres `Unicode` en la expresión regular (lo logré descubrir gracias a [**esta respuesta**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205643/17727129)):

```
text.match(/\[([\p{L}\s]*)\]|[\p{L}]*/gu)
```

---

**Código final:**

```js
let text = `En este campo las respuestas deben ir entre corchetes, ejemplo: El [oso polar] es de la Antártida y el [oso pardo] es de selva.`;
let cont = 0

text.match(/\[([\p{L}\s]*)\]|[\p{L}]*/gu)
  .forEach((item) => {
    if (item !== '') {
      cont++
      console.log(item + " " + cont);
    }
  });
```